# Ajax url local VS production

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I build webpage including few ajax functions, for example:

```
$.get('/Home/FutureRequestDialog', { FutureRequestID: futureReqID }, function (data) {
        $('#PopUpData').html(data);
        $("#edit_request_pop").modal('show');
    });
```

When i'm running it in localhost the action "FutureRequestDialog" fired as expected.
When i'm upload the webpage to production server, for example in the url - www.***.com/client - The ajax function don't find the url.
and i'm getting this error:

```
GET http://www.***.com/Home/FutureRequestDialog?FutureRequestID=15 404 (Not Found)
```

and it's true. the get url must be to the address:  http://www.***.com/client/Home/RequestDialog?RequestID=15

I don't want to edit the get url every time i want to debug my project in local and production. My project is ASP.net MVC.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
$.get('@Url.Action("FutureRequestDialog", "Home")', { FutureRequestID: futureReqID }, function (data) {
        $('#PopUpData').html(data);
        $("#edit_request_pop").modal('show');
    });
```